# Getting the new input value on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want to restrict a text input field with a float value to 2 decimal digits. I got it working with the keyup event: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nu73zxys/1/)

```
$("body").keyup(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).attr("id") == "number") {
        var value = $("#number").val();
        var decimalPointPosition = value.indexOf(".");
        if (decimalPointPosition >= 0) {
            var decimalCount = value.substring(decimalPointPosition + 1).length;
            if (decimalCount >= 2) {
                $("#number").val(value.substring(0, value.length - (decimalCount - 2)));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But the disadvantage is that with this solution its "flickering". So if I type in a 3rd decimal digit it first displays the 3rd digit then it's removed again, so it doesn't look so nice.
When using the keypress event I don't have the new value of the inout field just the new key in the event. Is there anyway to restrict the input value to 2 decimal digits other than the keyup event?

Thanks

Bernhard

Answer (score 0):

This I think is the only way ..

https://jsfiddle.net/yhb3d0hr/

```
$("body").keypress(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).attr("id") == "number") {
        var value = $("#number").val();
        var decimalPointPosition = value.indexOf(".");
        if (decimalPointPosition >= 0) {
            var decimalCount = value.substring(decimalPointPosition).length;
            if (decimalCount >= 2) {
                $("#number").val(value.substring(0, value.length - (decimalCount - 2)));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying a bit more and the key point is to get the cursor position, with the cursor position and the entered character it's possible to "predict" the entered input value.
So in my case, I don't allow more decimal digits when there are already 2 decimal digits entered, but it's possible to add number before the decimal point.
JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nu73zxys/4/

```
$("#number").keypress(function(e) {
    var value = $("#number").val();
    if (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) {
        var decimalPointPosition = value.indexOf(".");
        if (decimalPointPosition >= 0) {
            var decimalCount = value.substring(decimalPointPosition + 1).length;
            if (decimalCount == 2 && $("#number").getCursorPosition() > decimalPointPosition) {
                    e.preventDefault();                     
                }
        }
    }   
});
```